# In what condition that weak convergence may imply convergence of norms?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For example, if I have $u_n\to u$ weakly in $L^2(\Omega)$, I may conclude that 
$$
\liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_\Omega|u_n|^2dx\geq \int_\Omega |u|^2dx
$$
I am interested in, in what condition of $u_n$, I may acutally have 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_\Omega|u_n|^2dx= \int_\Omega |u|^2dx
$$
Thank you!

Comment: In $L^2$, you have $\lVert u_n - u\rVert \to 0$ if and only if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ (weak convergence) _and_ $\lVert u_n\rVert \to \lVert u\rVert$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a rather strong condition, since if the norms converge to the limit's norm in addition to weak convergence, then you have strong convergence $u_n\rightarrow u$; you can see this easily by expanding $\langle u-u_n,u-u_n\rangle$.